# Retrieve one column of data fom Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, ado.net

I am trying to fill a label with data from an access database.
But when I run the program the label disappears.
The connection with the database is working as the combobox 
gets its data from it. This is the code for the label so far.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{         
    string query2 = "SELECT Prijs FROM Klanten WHERE Naam='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'";
    OleDbDataAdapter prijsData = new OleDbDataAdapter(query2, connection);
    DataTable source2 = new DataTable();
    prijsData.Fill(source2);
    Lprijs.Text = source2.ToString();
    Lprijs.Update();
}
```

Comment: Lprijs.Text = source2.ToString(); Don't bind a full datatable to a label.text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select a row and a column from the `DataTable`:

```
Lprijs.Text = source2.Rows[0].Columns[0].ToString();
```

---

If you want to return only the first column of the first row, you can do this instead:

```
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query2, connection)) {
    Lprijs.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

No `OleDbDataAdapter` and no `DataTable` are required. [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the first column of the first row. The `using` statement automatically disposes the command at the end of the statement block, even if an exception should occur that terminates the statement block prematurely. You should enclose the connection in a `using` statement as well; this ensures that the connection will be closed and disposed.

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    // TODO:  Prepare commands etc.
    connection.Open();
    // TODO: Execute queries, etc.
}
```